# Objective C message dispatch mechanism

Tags: objective-c, performance

I am just staring to play around with Objective C (writing toy iPhone apps) and I am curious about the underlying mechanism used to dispatch messages.  I have a good understanding of how virtual functions in C++ are generally implemented and what the costs are relative to a static or non-virtual method call, but I don't have any background with Obj-C to know how messages are sent.  Browsing around I found [this](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations.html) loose benchmark and it mentions IMP cached messages being faster than virtual function calls, which are in turn faster than a standard message send.

I am not trying to optimize anything, just get deeper understanding of how exactly the messages get dispatched.

- How are Obj-C messages dispatched?
- How do Instance Method Pointers get cached and can you (in general) tell by reading the code  if a message will get cached?
- Are class methods essentially the same as a C function (or static class method in C++), or is there something more to them?

I know some of these questions may be 'implementation dependent' but there is only one implementation that really counts.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**How are Obj-C messages dispatched?**

Objective-C messages are dispatched using the runtime's `objc_msgSend()` function. Shown in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend), the function takes at least 2 arguments:

1. The receiving object
2. The selector of the message
3. [A variable list of arguments to the message being sent.]

Instances of a class have an `isa` pointer, which is a pointer to their class object. The selectors of methods in each object are stored in a "table" in the class object, and the `objc_msgSend()` function follows the `isa` pointer to the class object, to the find this table, and checks whether the method is in the table for the class. If it cannot find it, it looks for the method in the table of the class's superclass. If not found, it continues up the object tree, until it either finds the method or gets to the root object (`NSObject`). At this point, an exception is thrown.

**How do Instance Method Pointers get cached and can you (in general) tell by reading the code if a message will get cached?**

From Apple's Objective-C runtime guide on [Messaging](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW2):

> To speed the messaging process, the runtime system caches the selectors and addresses of methods as they are used. There’s a separate cache for each class, and it can contain selectors for inherited methods as well as for methods defined in the class. Before searching the dispatch tables, the messaging routine first checks the cache of the receiving object’s class (on the theory that a method that was used once may likely be used again). If the method selector is in the cache, messaging is only slightly slower than a function call. Once a program has been running long enough to “warm up” its caches, almost all the messages it sends find a cached method. Caches grow dynamically to accommodate new messages as the program runs.

As stated, caching starts to occur once the program is running, and after the program has been running long enough, most of the method calls will run through the cached method. As it also says, the caching occurs as the methods are used, so a message is only cached when it is used.

**Are class methods essentially the same as a C function (or static class method in C++), or is there something more to them?**

Class objects handle method despatch in a similar manner to that of instances of classes. Each class object has an object that stores its own *class* methods, in an object called a `metaclass`. The class object has its own `isa` pointer to its metaclass object, which in turn has super metaclass objects, which it can inherit class objects from. Method dispatch to class methods is as so:

1. The dispatch system follows the class object's `isa` pointer to the metaclass object
2. The metaclass object's method table is searched for the class method.
3. If not found, the search continues to the metaclass object's superclass, where the search continues.
4. This process repeats until either the method is found, or until it gets to the root metaclass, and an exception is thrown.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I find that understanding the dynamic dispatch system and how selectors are involved also explains rather well why method names must be unique, and Objective-C doesn't support overloaded methods in the same way Java and C++ do. Because the selector is cached as an integer, any method with the same name would map to the same selector. For better or for worse, it does force programmers to think more about properly naming methods.

Comment: If you want to go  deep... http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

Comment: What about the special 'forward' and 'performv' methods? When are they called?

Answer (score 4):

**Dispatch mechanisms**

It is used to find a necessary executable code when method was called(message sent)

- `Inline`
- `Static(Direct)`(C, Java `final`, C++ default, Swift `static`, `final`) - compiler knows the necessary method realisation at compile-time.
- `Dynamic` - is based on `witness table`(virtual table, dispatch table) and it introduce polymorphism

  - `Table`, V-Table(C++ `virtual`, Java default, Swift default) - Every object has a reference to class which has a table with all method addresses(super, overrides, new). SIL contains `vtable` or `witness_table`
  - `Message`(Objective-C, Swift `dynamic`) - Every **object** has a reference(isa) to **class** which contains a reference to **superclass** and **dispatch table**(which contains only realised methods(new  and which were overhead)) and don't contain methods from super. If method was not found in current dispatch table, it continue searching in superclass's dispatch table. This process is optimised by caching. SIL contains `volatile`
    Objective-C Message Dispatch

For example

```
class A {
    func foo1() {}
    func foo2() {}
}

class B: A {
    override func foo2() {}
    func foo3() {}
}
```

[image]

Objective-C obc_msgSend

```
id obc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...)
// self - object which receive a message
// op - selector of method
//... - arguments
```

If method implementation was not found for given selector you see next error

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```