# How to implement an IMP function that returns a large struct type determined at run-time?

Tags: objective-c, perl, objective-c-runtime

Background: CamelBones registers Perl classes with the Objective-C runtime.
To do this, every Perl method is registered with the same IMP
function; that function examines its `self` & `_cmd` arguments to find
which Perl method to call.

This has worked well enough for several years, for messages that were
dispatched with `objc_msgSend`. But now I want to add support for
returning floating-point and large struct types from Perl methods.
Floating-point isn't hard; I'll simply write another IMP that returns
double, to handle messages dispatched with `objc_msgSend_fpret`.

The question is what to do about `objc_msgSend_stret`. Writing a
separate `IMP` for every possible struct return type is impractical, for
two reasons: First, because even if I did so only for struct types
that are known at compile-time, that's an absurd number of functions.
And second, because we're talking about a framework that can be linked against any arbitrary Objective-C & Perl code, we *don't* know all the potential struct types when the framework is being compiled.

What I hope to do is write a single `IMP` that can handle any return
type that's dispatched via `objc_msgSend_stret`. Could I write it as
returning `void`, and taking a pointer argument to a return buffer, like
the old `objc_msgSend_stret` was declared? Even if that happened to
work for now, could I rely on it continuing to work in the future?

Thanks for any advice - I've been racking my brain on this one. :-)

**Update:**

Here's the advice I received from one of Apple's runtime engineers, on their objc-language mailing list:

> You must write assembly code to handle
>   this case.
>
> Your suggestion fails on some
>   architectures, where ABI for "function
>   returning void with a pointer to a
>   struct as the first argument" differs
>   from "function returning a struct".
>   (On i386, the struct address is popped
>   from the stack by the caller in one
>   case and by the callee in the other
>   case.) That's why the prototype for
>   `objc_msgSend_stret` was changed.
>
> The assembly code would capture the
>   struct return address, smuggle it into
>   non-struct-return C function call
>   without disturbing the rest of the
>   parameters, and then do the right
>   ABI-specific cleanup on exit (`ret $4`
>   on i386). Alternatively, the assembly
>   code can capture all of the
>   parameters. The forwarding machinery
>   does something like this. That code
>   might be in open-source CoreFoundation
>   if you want to see what the techniques
>   look like.

I'll leave this question open, in case someone brainstorms a better idea, but with this coming directly from Apple's own "runtime wrangler," I figure it's probably as authoritative an answer as I'm likely to get. Time to dust off the x86 reference manuals and knock the rust off my assembler-fu, I guess...

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't rely on the `void`-return and buffer way of doing things in the future. `objc_msgSend_stret` isn't going away any time soon, and so long as you allocate enough memory for the buffer, I think you should be fine. But it's certainly not the most elegant solution.

Comment: See above. Seems the easy way isn't reliable. Oh well, more or less what I expected.

Comment: @Sherm Alas! Good to know, though.

Comment: God, talk about being old. When I saw IMP I immediately though of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Message_Processor. Ah the hell with it ... I'm going to go have a beer.

Comment: perhaps you should answer you question, with the info from the apple engineer.

Comment: You might want to consult this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873776/using-nsmutabledictionary-as-backing-store-for-properties/5878637#5878637 Seems like you may be able to use the technique described to help with your situation--but it's a vague notion, not something I've completely thought through

Comment: Why not to use libffi closures?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the Apple engineer is right: the only to way to go is assembly code. Here are some usefull pointers to getting started:

- From the Objective-C runtime code: [The i386](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-i386.s) and [x86_64](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-x86_64.s) hand-crafted messenger assmbly stubs for the various messaging methods.
- [An SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982116/objective-c-message-dispatch-mechanism) that provides an overview of the dispatching.
- [A in-depth review](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/) of the dispatching mecanism with a line-by-line analysis of the assembly code

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but how to send messages with objc_msgSend* isn't the question I asked. I've had that part well in hand for years now. :-)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I took the problem in the wrong way. I have update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but that's still not what I'm looking for. I know how to send messages. That's not what I'm asking about. Congrats on the bounty though. :-)

Comment: My answer is pointing to the forwarding machinery as described by the Apple engineer, i.e. how a message is dispatched to the IMP. I thought it may be useful... :-(