# Obj-c protocol properties are not implemented in conforming class

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

## Problem

---

I've come across an interesting issue and wasn't able to find any documentation on it... **Sometimes `properties` declared in a `protocol` are not implemented in a particular class conforming to that `protocol` and a runtime exception occurs.** Are `dynamic property` definitions optimized away under some strange circumstance? Can `protocols` not be used with `properties` that were made to be declared `dynamic`? Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Below are some more details.

Given a `protocol`:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id someProperty;
@end
```

and a class implementing the `protocol` like so:

```
@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic someProperty;
@end
```

I've noticed that *sometimes* I am unable to get any information from calling

```
class_getProperty(myClass, propertyName);
```

for the `properties` in the `protocol`. This only happens to *some* classes and seems to be sporadic.

I'm running the latest Xcode 4 and linking against the iOS 6 SDK. I do have the pre-release Xcode 5 installed on the same machine though it is not the default (via xcode-select).

## Example

---

If you run this code:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id someData;

@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject <MyProtocol>

@end

@implementation MyObject

@dynamic someData;

@end
```

and then you run

```
const char *name = [@"someData" UTF8String];
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([MyObject class], name);
const char *attributes = property_getAttributes(property);
```

You WILL get meta data on the `property` EVEN THOUGH the `property` doesn't exist. In other words **you don't need to synthesize the property to get it's attributes**. The runtime still knows about it. Try it for yourself. The problem is that *sometimes* this doesn't happen. I want to know the conditions that cause the runtime to be unaware of the `property` attributes.

## Temporary Fix

---

My temporary fix is to just copy all the `property` definitions in the `protocol` and paste them into the .h file:

```
@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id someProperty;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic someProperty;
@end
```

This runs fine, though it is far from ideal. However, it suggests that my code is working correctly and the issue lies elsewhere.

I'd be happy to provide more details or background if needed.

Comment: The runtime doesn't optimize anything. The only thing that can optimize is the compiler (and sometimes the linker), but it's not that. A protocol is just a collection of declarations, there are no definitions inside whatsoever. **You** have to provide those, either by synthesizing the property or by implementing the accessor and the mutator manually.

Comment: By the way, this is not a question about Xcode.

Comment: The code you described is supposed to work. If you can write a test that doesn't work, please file a bug report and include that test.

Comment: @GregParker I think you were the only one who read my entire question.  Thanks for the comment! I'm on the same page with you about that I just wanted  to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion:

1. Declaring a property is enough for the property to exist at runtime. There is no need for implementation. This is how objective-c works. Methods don't have to exist at compile time, you can add them dynamically (e.g. what Core Data does).
2. `@dynamic` does absolutely nothing during runtime. At compile-time it's a placeholder which says "don't give me compiler warnings that the getter/setter is not defined here". On the newest LLVM it also says "don't synthesize automatically".

My suggestions:

1. If you are adding the protocol via a category, make sure the category is loaded. This seems to be the most usual problem with runtime reflection.
2. To debug, also try to use `class_conformsToProtocol`. It would be strange to have a class that conforms to a protocol without it having properties declared by the protocol.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions, thank you. I am doing something similar to what Core Data does with it's models. Thank you for these suggestions. I'll most likely mark this as the answer if nobody else has any input.

Comment: @Christopher Well, core data doesn't use the property declarations as far as I know. The beauty of core data is they can use the data model to generate property getters/setters.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not mimicking Core Data under the hood but I am automatically generating accessor methods for classes (though based on the types of their properties not data models). For reference, the code that I'm actually using this in is here: https://github.com/FuturaIO/ParseModel-iOS

Comment: `class_conformsToProtocol` tells me it is conforming yet the property attributes cannot be retrieved. As Greg mentioned in another comment, this may be a bug. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

protocols define methods, optional methods and required methods.

properties are abstracted methods, if the protocol defines a property as being required then you must implement the required methods: typically with `@synthesize`... but can be done in other ways

(assuming non-fragile ABI / Modern Runtime) Using readonly for simplicity

```
@property(readonly)int dog;
```

could be implimented:

```
@synthesize dog;
```

or

```
@synthesize dog = _dog; // synthesize standard getter for the iVar _dog
```

or

```
- (int) dog
{
    return _dog; // or dog, or cat/5 or 5 or whatever
}
```

**EDIT: re dynamic properties**

`@dynamic` is a keyword that does nothing to generate methods to satisfy the requirement of a property, what it does do is inform the compiler that it is "taken care of" in some other way...

this dynamic dispatch can be accomplished by a few different methods at runtime, one would be by adding method implementations at run time, another would be by using the runtime for unresolved selectors. (I had a similar question about using dynamic properties to use a generic KV store in a Dictionary)

see: [Using NSMutableDictionary as backing store for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873776/using-nsmutabledictionary-as-backing-store-for-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Grady but there was some confusion with the question so I have revised it.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging and testing I've concluded that this is a bug. If anyone has any contrary evidence or suggestions feel free to post. The bug is this:

***Sometimes*** when a `property` is defined in a `protocol` and then a class conforms to said `protocol`, the runtime is unaware of the `property's` attributes (e.g. class_getProperty fails) if the `property` is flagged as `dynamic`.

Rememeber, `dynamic` provides *no implementation*, it simply suppresses warnings, however, the `property` attributes should still be retrievable via the runtime.

I wanted to add some useful code snippets to solving / debugging these types of problems:

```
- (NSArray *)propertyNamesForClass:(Class)aClass includeInherited:(BOOL)shouldIncludeInherited;
{
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
    uint propertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertyCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
        [names addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])]];
    }

    if (shouldIncludeInherited) {
        Class superClass = aClass;
        while ((superClass = class_getSuperclass(superClass))) {
            uint superPropertyCount = 0;
            objc_property_t *superProperties = class_copyPropertyList(superClass, &superPropertyCount);
            for (uint i = 0; i < superPropertyCount; i++) {
                [names addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(superProperties[i])]];
            }
        }
    }

    NSArray *sortedNames = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return sortedNames;
}

- (NSArray *)protocolNamesForClass:(Class)aClass includeInherited:(BOOL)shouldIncludeInherited;
{
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
    uint protocolCount = 0;
    __unsafe_unretained Protocol **protocolArray = class_copyProtocolList(aClass, &protocolCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < protocolCount; i++) {
        [names addObject:NSStringFromProtocol(protocolArray[i])];
    }

    if (shouldIncludeInherited) {
        Class superClass = aClass;
        while ((superClass = class_getSuperclass(superClass))) {
            uint superProtocolCount = 0;
            __unsafe_unretained Protocol **superProtocolArray = class_copyProtocolList(superClass, &superProtocolCount);
            for (uint j = 0; j < superProtocolCount; j++) {
              [names addObject:NSStringFromProtocol(superProtocolArray[j])];
            }
        }
    }

    NSArray *sortedNames = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return sortedNames;
}

- (NSArray *)propertyNamesForProtocol:(Protocol *)aProtocol
{
    NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
    uint protocolPropertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = protocol_copyPropertyList(aProtocol, &protocolPropertyCount);
    for (uint j = 0; j < protocolPropertyCount; j++) {
        [names addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[j])]];
    }

    NSArray *sortedNames = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return sortedNames;
}
```

Comment: I've packaged these and other related methods up for convenience here: https://github.com/mstrchrstphr/NSRuntime