# Creating a Model Object with an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is something I have been playing with, and have yet to make my mind up about.

When querying a database, it is extremely common that you will use the data in the response to create custom model objects. Let's use 'Book' as an example.

I have received `JSON` describing multiple `Book` objects. I parse the `JSON` into an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s. I now have a few options:

- Make all properties on `Book` mutable (I hate this option). You could then have a `BookManager` class with takes an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s and maps the data in the dictionary to the correct properties.
- Add an initialiser to the `Book` object which accepts the important details.

Example:

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title author:(NSString *)author publishDate:(NSDate *)publishDate;
```

The aforementioned `BookManager` class could then take the `NSDictionary`s as before, but create the `Book` objects with this initialiser. This is nice, because you could then make all of the public facing properties on `Book` `readonly`. However, it is very limited, and if (as is often the case) there are a lot of properties on the model, this is not feasible.

- Add an initialiser to `Book` which accepts the `NSDictionary` representation of itself. I dislike this approach in one way because I feel the responsibility is not the model's to create itself from a dictionary. I prefer the idea of a manager class mapping the dictionary to the model. However, I do like the fact that it means that all properties can be `readonly`.

**There is no doubt in my mind I am missing other options, and if you are aware of them, please point them out. The aim of this question is to finally determine the best way to approach this scenario.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873776/using-nsmutabledictionary-as-backing-store-for-properties

Comment: For the general case I prefer an init method that accepts a dictionary.  This scheme is quite flexible, it "cascades" naturally when you have a superclass or inner dictionaries with sub-objects, and you can if you wish use a common core that makes use of KVC to do some of the inits.  (Hint, use a mutable dictionary and remove keys as you "consume" them.  Then whatever's left can be consumed by the "common core".)

Comment: Look into Mantle - might be easier and more generic https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/blob/master/Mantle/MTLManagedObjectAdapter.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regularly use an init method with the important arguments, but yes, it becomes very unwieldily when the number of arguments reach double digits and/or several of the arguments can be nil.  The longest such method I have seen in the iOS SDK is `CLLocation`'s

```
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
                altitude:(CLLocationDistance)altitude
      horizontalAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)hAccuracy
        verticalAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)vAccuracy
                  course:(CLLocationDirection)course
                   speed:(CLLocationSpeed)speed
               timestamp:(NSDate *)timestamp
```

Regarding your last option, adding an `initWithDictionary:` method to `Book` could be expanded to also include a class-level method for creating instances of `Book` from an `NSDictionary`.

```
+ (instancetype)bookWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
```

And optionally a convenient way to get a dictionary representation from a `Book` instance.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation
```

If you search the iOS documentation for "withDictionary" and "dictionaryRepresentation" you will see a few places where this is used.  In other SDKs, you will sometimes see the method named as `someObjectFromDictionary:`

Comment: The unfortunate part of this pattern is you move all of the verbosity you would have reserved for the arguments of the function to a bunch of strings.  Compound that with ambiguous types in a dictionary and you kind of wind up right back where you started, but with even less type safety than before.

Answer (score 0):

I think  u can do this using JSONModel

see this

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-jsonmodel--cms-19840
https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel

Comment: This is basically having the model itself map the dictionary keys to their respective properties.