# How does UITableView delegation send message to tableview?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates

So I have a view controller which adopts UITableViewDelegate:

```
@interface MyViewController:UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabelView *myTableView;
@end
```

In the implementation file MyViewController.m, I override

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

My question is, how does the height of tabel view row get returned to myTableView and further sets the height of each individual row?

Edited:
Just to be clear, I tried to implement this mechanism in my own custom view class where specific information is asked for to lay out the view. I have no problem using UITabelView itself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question isn't very clear but the code inside the UITableView which asks the delegate for the cell height would simply be something like this.

```
CGFloat thisCellHeight = [self.delegate tableView:self heightForRowAtIndexPath:thisCellIndexPath];
```

It send a message back to the delegate and asks...

Comment: @trapper, so when the line "return xxx;" inside -(CGFloat)tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:  is executed, another delegate message is sent out back to the table view?

Comment: Not exactly. The message is initiated by the UITableView and sent to the delegate, the delegates return value (the CGFloat) is the only thing returned back to the UITableView

Comment: If you are interested in the 'under the hood' implementation of how messaging actually works then there is a lot to read, but this is probably more detail than you need. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982116/objective-c-message-dispatch-mechanism