# Capture arguments of static method calls using Kiwi

Tags: ios, mocking, kiwi

This [link](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi/wiki/Mocks-and-Stubs#capturing-arguments) shows how to capture an argument of a mock object using Kiwi.

Is there a way to capture arguments of static method calls? It seems to me that this only work with instance methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the same [message dispatching mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982116/objective-c-message-dispatch-mechanism) is used for both instance and class methods, you can safely spy on class methods.

```
@interface MyObject: NSObject
+ (void)doNoOpWithObject:(NSObject*)obj;
@end

@implementation MyObject
+ (void)doNoOpWithObject:(id)object {}
@end


SPEC_BEGIN(StaticSpy)
it(@"captures static method arguments", ^{
    KWCaptureSpy *spy = [MyObject captureArgument:@selector(doNoOpWithObject:) atIndex:0];
    [MyObject doNoOpWithObject:@18];
    [[spy.argument should] equal:@18];
});
SPEC_END
```