# where static / class methods are stored in objective c

Tags: objective-c, oop, static-methods, class-method

Suppose we declare a class as follows in `MyClass.h` file as follows.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject


+(void)aClassMethod;

@end
```

And in `MyClass.m` File..

```
@implementation MyClass

+(void)aClassMethod{

NSLog(@"It is a Class method");

}
@end
```

My question is that after compilation where this `aClassMethod` will be stored??
and if we declare some member functions , then where they will be stored.

Comment: maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982116/objective-c-message-dispatch-mechanism or if you need more depth: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/

Comment: Actually I wanted to know that where class method is stored in stack , code or data segment??

And what tasks are done bye the compiler to handle the class methods?

Comment: you should alter your question.

Comment: What you referred to as a member function is called an *instance method* in Objective-C.

Comment: By the way, Objective-C class methods are not analogous to static methods in other languages.

Comment: @MohanChaudhari To expand a bit on jlehr's answer, if you `clang -rewrite-objc main.c` your program, you'll see class methods turn to static C functions, so they are marked as such in the generated object. The details of equivalent C questions about memory layout apply to Objective-C, since the difference is that an Objective-C program is linked with a runtime that executes the message dispatch as indicated above by vikingosegundo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C methods are compiled into C functions, which are stored in the program's Text segment along with any other C functions the program defines. That's true for both class and instance methods.

Answer (score 3):

> Actually I wanted to know that where class method is stored in stack , code or data segment?? And what tasks are done bye the compiler to
>   handle the class methods?

This question doesn't fully make sense.

The executable code is stored where all executable code is stored;  in the mach-o TEXT segments.  The code is mapped into memory on readonly, executable, pages of memory.   The memory cannot be made readwrite (i.e.  you can't edit the executable in memory).

Objective-C methods are standard C functions that always take two arguments;  `self` and `_cmd`.

In terms of *calling convention*, the code is called like any other C function.   The only difference being the method dispatch mechanism that matches the call site (`[NSObject new]`) to the executable code to be invoked.   That matching is done through the Objective-C messenger and is implemented by `objc_msgSend()` or some variant.