# why the instance method that is "methodSignatureForSelector:" can be invoke by the class object

Tags: objective-c, nsinvocation

What make me doubt is that the class object can invoke instance method.

The method of "`methodSignatureForSelector` is instance method 
but when I invoke it by instance object, it go wrong.

```
NSString *classStr = @"NSInvocationObject";

// 获取class
Class objClass = NSClassFromString(classStr);

// 获取函数
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"classTest");

// 获取对象
Class stclass = [objClass class];
// - (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector OBJC_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE(""); here is a instance method ,but be invoke by objClass 
NSMethodSignature *singature = [objClass methodSignatureForSelector:selector];

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:singature];

invocation.target = objClass;
invocation.selector = selector;
[invocation invoke];ere
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Selector

- Selector identifies method by name, not method implementations.
- The `hallo` method in one class has the same selector as `hallo` method in another class.
- A class method and an instance method with the same name have assigned the same selector.

Selector just identifies method by name and it's irrelevant if it's a class or an instance.

- `-(void)hallo;` -> selector = `hallo`
- `+(void)hallo;` -> selector = `hallo`

### NSMethodSignature

Method signature describes type information of the return value and parameters. It doesn't say anything about method name, if it's an instance method, a class method, ... *Just types*.

- `-(void)hallo;` - signature/encoding = `v@:`

  - `v` - void, return type
  - `@` - object
  - `:` - selector
- `+(void)hallo;` - signature/encoding = `v@:`

[Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100) for more info.

To make it more obvious, imagine you have following methods:

```c
- (void)foo {
}

+ (NSUInteger)foo {
    return 2;
}
```

Both of them have `foo` as a selector, but they do differ in encoding:

- `-(void)foo` - signature/encoding = `v@:`
- `+(NSUInteger)foo` - signature/encoding = `Q@:`

### Usage

Here's an example. If your class method & instance method equals (name & return type & parameter types), you can use the same selector and method signature on the class and on the instance. `invokeWithTarget:` says - send a message (identifier by selector = method name & signature = return value & parameter types) - `target` can be anything that can receive this message.

Simplified a bit, but should explain what's going on here.

Sample class:

```c
@interface MyClass: NSObject

+(void)hallo; // Class method
-(void)hallo; // Instance method

@end

@implementation MyClass

+(void)hallo {
    NSLog(@"classHallo");
}

-(void)hallo {
    NSLog(@"instanceHallo");
}

@end
```

Invocations:

```c
Class c = [MyClass class];   // Class of MyClass
MyClass *i = [MyClass new];  // Instance of MyClass

// Selector identifies method by name
// It's irrelevant if it's a class or an instance method
SEL selector = @selector(hallo);

// Signature just contains types of return value & parameters
// It's irrelevant if it's a class or an instance method
// Get a signature of the +hallo method
NSMethodSignature *signature = [c methodSignatureForSelector:selector];

// Create invocation
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.selector = selector;  // Set the selector
[invocation invokeWithTarget:c]; // Invokes +hallo (class)
[invocation invokeWithTarget:i]; // Invokes -hallo (instance)

// Get a signature of the -hallo method
signature = [i methodSignatureForSelector:selector];

// Create invocation
invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.selector = selector;  // Set the selector
[invocation invokeWithTarget:c]; // Invokes +hallo (class)
[invocation invokeWithTarget:i]; // Invokes -hallo (instance)
```

### Documentation

Archived, but still good to learn about:

- [Type Encodings](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100)
- [Selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html)

### Comments

> `MyClass` only have a instance method: `-(void)hallo;` but when I execute the `NSMethodSignature *signature = [c methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(hallo)]`, I can't get a signature of the method, signature is `nil`, if the selector just identifies method by name and it's irrelevant if it's a class or an instance, I should get a signature of method.

No. Check the [`methodSignatureForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571960-methodsignatureforselector) method `aSelector` argument documentation:

> A selector that identifies the method for which to return the implementation address. **When the receiver is an instance, aSelector should identify an instance method; when the receiver is a class, it should identify a class method.**

What selector identifies? Method by name and it's `hallo` in our case - NOT `+(void)hallo` and NOT `-(void)hallo`, just `hallo` - this is what I meant with irrelevant comment.

> **When the receiver is an instance, aSelector should identify an instance method;**

`i` is the receiver, `i` is an instance, so the following code asks for the `-(void)hallo` method signature, not `+(void)hallo`.

```c
MyClass *i = [MyClass new];   // Instance of MyClass
SEL selector = @selector(hallo);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [i methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
```

> **when the receiver is a class, it should identify a class method.**

`c` is the receiver, `c` is a class, so the following code asks for the `+(void)hallo` method signature, not `-(void)hallo`.

```c
Class c = [MyClass class];   // Class of MyClass
SEL selector = @selector(hallo);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [c methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
```

---

There's also [`+ (NSMethodSignature *)instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571959-instancemethodsignatureforselect?language=objc) which you can invoke on a class to get an instance method selector:

```c
Class c = [MyClass class];   // Class of MyClass
SEL selector = @selector(hallo);
NSMethodSignature *signature = [c instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
```

---

> i think i had understanded why the class object can inkove instance method, the class object's isa point to a meta-class that the meat-class is still a NSObject type (same as meta-class : NSObject) ; so the class object is same to a isntance object in the sense , this mean that class'object and instance'object can inkove instance method

I either don't understand what do you mean with this or you're misusing the *instance method* term.

[Objective-C Classes Are also Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW18):

> In Objective-C, **a class is itself an object** with an opaque type called Class. Classes can’t have properties defined using the declaration syntax shown earlier for instances, but **they can receive messages**.

[Objects Send and Receive Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW2)

> Sending an Objective-C message is conceptually very much like calling a C function.

`[i hallo]` actually means *send a `hallo` message to `i`* & `[c hallo]` actually means *send a `hallo` message to `c`* where `i` is an instance and `c` is a `Class`.

It seems to me that you're just using wrong term. If I understood your comment correctly, yes, you can send a message to either an instance or a class.

Here're other resources related to this topic:

- [Objective C message dispatch mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982356/581190)
- [Objective-C Direct Methods](https://nshipster.com/direct/) (new stuff)

Comment: now, my code like this : MyClass only have a instance method : -(void)hello;  but when i execute the code that "NSMethodSignature *signature = [c methodSignatureForSelector:selector]", i can't get a signature of the method, signature is nil, if the selector just identifies method by name and it's irrelevant if it's a class or an instance. i should get a signature of method.

Comment: i konw that if the name of method is same ,it's selector is same, but it usually is the same method name in difference class object , not the difference from Class'method  to instance'method, what i mean that Class object should invoke class'method, instance object should invoke instance'method, because  class'method be store at meta-class. instance'method be store class, it's not be allowed class invoke instance'mehtod

Comment: See my updated answer, **Comments** section (at the end).

Comment: yeah, what you say about the selector is ture, but is not my doubt. i think i had understanded why the class object can inkove instance method, the class object's isa point to a meta-class that the meat-class is still a NSObject  type (same as meta-class : NSObject) ; so the class object is same to a isntance object in the sense , this mean that class'object and instance'object can inkove instance method ,

Comment: anyway, what you say stail help me a lot

Comment: Did update my answer again (end of it). I think (or at least I hope) I finally understood what are you asking for.