# Read ARP cache from machine

Tags: cocoa, arp

I'm working on a program that read arp cache from machine. I'm using Cocoa. There's a library called libdnet (libdnet.sourceforge.net) which has arp reading function. But I don't know how to write a code to use that function. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know C and apply that knowledge to call [the library's functions](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/dnet.3.txt). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180549/learn-c-first-before-learning-objective-c) for links to C-learning resources.

Objective-C is a superset of C, so you'll be able to integrate the C code to call those functions into your Objective-C methods just fine once you know both languages.

Comment: thanks a lot Peter. I'll try building the required knowledge.