# Iphone app in pure c language

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks

I want to know if we can develop an iphone app for ios 6 using pure c language in Xcode.

Or is there any cross compiler from c to objective c.

Please suggest me.

Comment: See this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c

Comment: It is possible to write a whole app in C, but it is going to be very ugly. There is an existing question about this.

Answer (score 0):

GCC can compile Objective-C code. Look it [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Objective-C is extension of C. 
If you need to compile from C to Objective-C look at standard [llvm compiler](http://llvm.org/) and use `msg_send` instead of blocks

Answer (score 0):

Re-inventing the Wheel!!!

Yeah, you can develop iphone app in pure C, but what about all large sets of APIs given to you that will save hunderds hours of coding, testing, performance testing?

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c), and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/going-further-with-c-for-ios-development).

There are few apps that can be used as [titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/).