# Objective-C best practice for using class methods

Tags: objective-c, instance, class-method

I am used to functional programming. Now writing for iOS I find myself using class methods (+)  frequently, rather than creating instances (from -).

Usually I use class methods for small, recurring tasks - like sending async requests, updating database, storing/retrieving preferences etc.

Is this the right thing to do, or should I try to change my thinking more and start using instances instead? Is it even possible to avoid using class methods all together?

Comment: If you can't stop yourself from using only C, there is a way (though it is not recommended) you can get an [app up and running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c).

Comment: @CodaFi always gotta be pimpin me out, huh?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Says the one that's trolling month-old questions ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best recommendation would be to look at how Foundation and Cocoa is doing and do it similarly. There is a place for class methods in Objective-C.

Some examples of class methods include

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    // Animation here...
}];
```

and

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *date, NSError *error) {
                           // Handle response here ...
                       }];
```

Comment: Those are more of convenience methods and initializers (especially the animation one) than tried and true class methods, but I see your point.  +1

Answer (score 2):

There is a third alternative supported by Objective C for encapsulating functionality that does not need implicit access to instance variables - it is using "plain" C functions. Unlike class functions, "plain" C functions do not use virtual dispatch, which may be important in vary tight loops.

Note that class methods provide more functionality than, say, `static` methods of Java, C++, and C#: they support overriding, letting class method in base classes use more specific implementations in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are used when you do not need any instance of the class, and your purpose gets served only by a method call of that like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

---

In MRC

The `alloc/init` combination gives you an owning reference. That means you must `release` it later on. The classMethod returns a non-owning reference. You may not release it.

i.e.,

```
Person *firstPerson=[Person personWithName:@"AnoopVaidya" address:@"India"];
```

In ARC, for the above there is not such differnce.

Comment: I would say that class methods serve a far broader purpose than that.  I can, for instance, make a little "singleton" out of a static variable and make the class method an accessor.

Comment: @CodaFi: Yes that should be in Answer :)