# how to implement UIView method in ANSI-C++?

Tags: objective-c

I have something like this:

```
// main.m
@interface MYView : UIView { @public int counter; } @end;
@implementation MYView 
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
}
@end
```

now I would like to remove drawRect method (or any other method) from implementation here, and move it to C++ file utility.cpp.

The reason why I need this, is that I must use some C++ library, that will not compile in Objective-C++. And I need to use that library intensively so that just switching back and forth is not convenient.

I know I can simly do this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    call_cpp_function(rect);
}
```

but maybe I can just completely define the method in c++? Something like this:

```
void __magic_declaration__ MYView::drawRect(CPPTYPE(CGRect))
// note, this line is completely my own imagination, this is just to illustrate what I want.
```

Comment: I'm sorry for asking but why do you want to do this?

Comment: The reason why I need this, is that I must use some C++ library, that will not compile in Objective-C++.

Comment: Sorry, I got that from your question. Why are you drawing with C++ code (or is drawing only one simple example)?

Comment: Yes, I need to hook up many methods and callbacks to something like interpreted language written in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, if not exactly what you'd call pleasant. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290255/15371) in which a view is constructed and drawn in pure C.

Comment: Hey look, it's my answer! You beat me to it, hah.

Comment: Yes I know it's yours. You're world famous now for going to deep roots)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. The closest you can get is calling C++ code from an ObjC method as you mentioned.

Technically you might be able to hack something up that adds the method dynamically using the ObjC runtime API, but that will be much clunkier, harder, and slower.