# Using Objective C classes from C code

Tags: objective-c, c, macos

I know it is possible to use Objective C code using objc_msgSend to, I believe, manually run the Objective C runtime however when I run this code I get errors referencing NSString (even though I never use it) as well as other un-used classes.

Errors from xcode

[image]

I have the Objective C Code above it (commented out) that I am trying to 'mimic'.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h> /*Added suggestion by answer, same errors*/
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main()
{
// convert objective c into c code
/*
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setAlertStyle:NSInformationalAlertStyle];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Hello World"];
    [alert setInformativeText:@"Hello World"];
    [alert runModal];
*/
    id alert = objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSAlert"), sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("init"));
    objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setAlertStyle:"), NSInformationalAlertStyle);
    objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setMessageText:"), CFSTR("Hello World!"));
    objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setInformativeText:"), CFSTR("Hello World!"));
    objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("runModal"));
}
```

Comment: Do not call objc_msgSend() without a cast to a function pointer type that matches the method's signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing some imports.

`objc_msgSend` is declared in `<objc/message.h>`.

`objc_getClass` is declared in `<objc/runtime.h>`.

`sel_getUid` and `sel_registerName` are declared in `<objc/objc.h>`.

Now, given that `<objc/objc.h>` is already imported by `<objc/runtime.h>`, importing the latter along with `<objc/message.h`> should suffice.

I tested it with the following example and it works as expected

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> // Needed for CFSTR
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <objc/message.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    id alert = (id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend((id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSAlert"), sel_registerName("alloc")), sel_registerName("init"));
    (void (*)(id, SEL, int))objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setAlertStyle:"), 1); // NSInformationalAlertStyle is defined in AppKit, so let's just use 1
    (void (*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setMessageText:"), CFSTR("Hello World!"));
    (void (*)(id, SEL, id))objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("setInformativeText:"), CFSTR("Hello World!"));
    (int (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend(alert, sel_getUid("runModal"));
}
```

#### Note

I added the explicit cast to `objc_msgSend` as suggested by Greg Parker in the comments.

Comment: Didn't work same errors even with the line #include <Foundation/Foundation.h> before importing AppKit

Comment: Ok, I managed to do it. Check my example in the updated answer

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, I'll try creating a new xcode project.

Comment: I created a Cocoa Application and placed the code above in the `main.m`. I'll add a screenshot with code and result.

Comment: Ok it worked but I think it does defeat the purpose of not using Objective C, oh well thanks for the help!

Comment: Well the headers you are imported are C headers, why do you think it defeats it?

Comment: Oh, almost forgot. This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c

Comment: I was attempting to avoid using the objective c compiler (which I assume this is needed) so as to be able to compile asm (translating the c code to asm) code in nasm

Comment: But oh well I'll see what I can do, I could very well be missing something obvious :P

Comment: Ok I modified the example to make it fully C compatible. Provided that you link the `CoreFoundation` framework and an Objective-C runtime library, you can compile it with a C compiler like `clang` or `gcc`.

Comment: Do not call objc_msgSend() without a cast to a function pointer type that matches the method's signature.

Comment: @GregParker thanks for the input! Can you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: @GregParker If I get it right, it should be something like my last edit. I'm still trying to fully understand the implications.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella According to the C ABI, vararg vs. statically typed call sites cannot be used interchangeably everywhere.