# Is there any documentation or exanples on how to call Objective-C objects from assembly language?

Tags: objective-c, macos, assembly

Is there any documentation or examples on how to call Objective-C objects from assembly language on Mac OS X?

Comment: Forget assembly, even C presents a great challenge! Here is [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10289890/335858) for iOS, but it should give you a decent idea of what is required to build a tiny hello-world app without Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirectly; Objective-C calls compile down to calls to the C function [`objc_msgSend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend) so you can use the usual C ABI to get into there. Which you can look up for your target architecture of interest [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/000-Introduction/introduction.html).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much.