# Will learning Objective-C before C help you pick up C later on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I'm a novice programmer looking to build my own iOS app. I'm hearing a lot of mixed responses on how it may or may not be necessary to learn C before taking on `Objective-C`.

I'm leaning towards learning `Objective-C` first considering I can always look back into the `C` (I'm using Big Nerd Ranch Guide for `Objective-C`) for some concepts like `structs`, `arrays`, etc.

I'm open to hearing any advice on what any of you may think!

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. So once you know Objective-C it means you already know C.

Comment: IMO, in order to effectively program in Objective-C, you need to know everything needed to effectively program in C along with the Obj-C knowledge.

Comment: Cocoa suggests a style that avoids the legacy gnarliness of C. After an ObjC background, one would still have to relearn C-style arrays, pointers, memory allocation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Learn C language first. Because most of the low level computer programming stuff might be covered by that and you may get to learn how to program with much primary capabilities provided within the language. Because this is mostly Procedure Oriented Programming (POP).

Then move on to learn Objective-C which is an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) Language. Here you can use the skills you used to program using that primary language and you might feel that you are provided much power within the Objective-C and also be able to describe and make use of world in more Object-Oriented manner!

And must remember, as you are going to implement iOS Applications, you better have a good knowledge about Objective-C before moving to learn Apples new language for its products like Mac OS X and iOS, which is Swift! Because Objective-C has been used by them for a long period of time, and still it's been used by them.

Here read the following question and it's answers if you want to clarify more:
[Learn C first before learning Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180549/learn-c-first-before-learning-objective-c)

**Hint:** Seems like your Question also might be closed sooner enough saying it's been duplicated or answered before! :-)

Answer (score -2):

My advice would be to forget about both C and Objective-C and learn [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/). It's an easier, more contemporary language and the future of iOS development.

Comment: Do not waste your time on Objective-C ; you may as well start with Object Pascal. Or Logo. On iOS, Swift is the way to go.